# How does Yoga Perdana colorize his illustrations?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, gradient

If you haven't heard of him or seen any of his work, Yoga Perdana is a digital artist who, in my opinion, creates some really awesome illustrations with a very soft feel to them.

[image: Yoga Perdana Logo Exploration]

[image: Yoga PerdanaLogo Exploration]

I believe I understand how he lays out his illustrations using circles, but I'm unsure of how he gives his art such a soft feel to it. There are definitely gradients involved, but his come out so different looking compared to mine.

Any ideas on the process Yoga takes in order to colorize his images while maintaining a very soft feel to them? Are there any tutorials available?

This is what I have so far:
[image: Yoga Remake Attempt]

[image: Yoga Remake Attempt With Anchors]

I went off of Yoga's initial construction design, creating circles, using minus front to create the initial ring shape, and then using the outline pathfinder to create anchor points where the rings intersected. From there I deleted curves correspondingly to look like the original logo.

How do I connect all of the points to become a singular shape so I can add a gradient?

**UPDATE (11:15pm):** Just got the gradient working. I ended up joining the disconnected paths to create singular shapes in which I could insert a fill into. From there I selected all of my new shapes and filled them with a gradient.

[image: Gradient Filled Perdana Remake]

This brings me to my next question, *how do I create the shadows within the logo to create a sense of depth?* I'm thinking about duplicating the shapes, creating a shadow gradient for each one, and altering their opacity to around 40%.

**UPDATE (1/9/15):** I was able to add some shadows to give the logo depth. All I did was duplicate pieces of the logo so that they were overlaid right on top of each other, and added some fade gradients to them.

[image: Yoga Remake Attempt With Shadows]

However, I think there's still something that differentiates Yoga's logo from mine. Is he using some sort of grain or blur technique? I can't put my finger on it, but I definitely feel like something's different.

**UPDATE (1/9/15 @ 5:01pm):** I exported my logo as a png and loaded it up in Photoshop. Added some very fine grain (0.5 gaussian noise) and gave it a dark background to accompany it. Here is how it came out, Yoga's is on the left, mine on the right:

[image: My First Submission of Yoga's Final Redesign]

I realize the shape of the logo is not exactly the same as Yoga's, but I'd say it looks very similar design wise. Please give me any tips on how I can improve.

Til next time.
-Chris

Comment: Hey there Ruby! Do you have any examples of things you've tried that you don't feel like have worked well? Barring googling, "Yoga Perdana Tutorials" (which I'm sure you've already done), looking at specific issues you're having with matching the style might be a good place to start here.

Comment: Showing us what you've tried and perhaps also a logo that you don't feel is "soft" as you put it would be helpful. I suspect a simple inspection of the histogram of Yoga's work compared to work you find isn't as soft will reveal a lot.

Comment: I just added an image of what I have so far!

Comment: Your edit is almost there! You can add a gradient which is black to transparent, which will give you the shadow effect.

Comment: Hey Chris - would you be willing to record a video of you creating this?  Even if it's just a replay with no explanation it would be super helpful

Comment: Hey all, it's me. I saw someone ask for a tutorial on this above, would anyone else find a video tutorial w/ explanation helpful? I actually have a Youtube channel dedicated to dev tutorials, but would def be down to expand to design if others are interested. Let me know, I'll be checking in.

Answer (score 3):

The way you can achieve the soft shading similar to the examples you've showed is to create a new shape that has a gradient fade from black to black with 0% transparency on one end. 
[image]

Create a duplicate of the shape you want to add the shadow to, and use it as a clipping mask for your "shadow"(cmd/ctrl+7).
[image]

Then drag that over the main shape (or you could have pasted the clipping mask in place and it would already be overlayed) to achieve each shadow. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial imitating his style here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=it8jF089HA4 that you might find helpful. The person in the video is using Sketch.

Comment: Hi user57152, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!

Comment: Hey - I actually did that imitation. 

Unfortunately, I have no idea how he does the gradients, and it is not in this video.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can brush the shadow instead of relying on the software default?As you are the one who can control the depth of the image, like which should be on top of which shape.

Answer (score 0):

Gradient: Move it a bit to give it more blue, notice bottom right quarter

Shadows are the thing that need most work, for start add overlay of 7% black to all shapes that are in the back, later when you add gradient make it much smoother, your transition now is too aggressive at some places, also use radial gradient