# How to create Graphics like this in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, gradient-mesh

I am a developer and hence I am not experienced in photoshop and graphic designing. I recently came across a graphic like this:

[image: Overlapping Gradient]

I want to know how can I create an image like this Photoshop?

The reason for recreating the image is that I want to change color order of the gradient.

Tutorials, Suggestions anything would do.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** I seriously had no idea where to start. Thank you guys for all the comments and tips.

Comment: Sure but would be more appropriate to use illustrator

Comment: You should start with what can you do and then ask the question about what you can't do. There are 3 key points in this image. The base shape, the bridging lines, the gradient. Where is it you get stuck? — On another note. The person who made this did a poor job with the bridging lines. They're a bit rough. — Also, instead of remaking that, would `Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Hue/Saturation...` work?

Comment: @Joonas yes you can also see some confkation artefacts in the image.

Comment: Using Photoshop might be possible, however it would be like using a hammer to screw in a nail.  It's just not the right software for the job. Use a vector image editor instead.

Comment: Too broad of a question. Suggestions are too personal, and there are tons of tutorials on the internet, just pick one and let us know if you get stuck during the process. Even on this website you can find examples, like this https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/65092/how-does-yoga-perdana-colorize-his-illustrations

Answer (score 3):

In Photoshop, there is no elegant way I know of. Maybe you could create a linear gradient and bend it the way you want, but that's a lot of hassle.

However, if Illustrator is an option, you can just create the form using the path tool and then apply a vertical gradient stroke to it.

[image: Illustrator Gradient palette]

If you need your graphic in Ps, you can simply copy and paste it as a Smart Object, leaving you with all options to change it later. However, you will not have access to the gradient via Photoshop's native tools.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a vector image editor instead, not Photoshop which is a raster image editor, and the wrong kind of software for making logos.

The example below was made in Inkscape, but almost any vector image editor will do, such as Adobe Illustrator, CorelDraw, etc. It consists of a single path (shown stroked in green below) broken up into various pieces, gradients applied to the each of the strokes, and a couple of shapes filled with a semi transparent gradient for the shadows.

[image]

Here are the gradients I used. These could be easily edited to change the colours.

[image]